# Reload postgres database config at runtime

Tags: scala, akka

I am using a greenplum cluster where you can submit query only to the master.
I have the master node ip in the application.conf.
But the IP for master node switches to different machines due to high availability etc.

application.conf entries:

```
database = {
  connectionPool = "HikariCP"
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    serverName = "103.10.11.6"
    portNumber = "5432"
    databaseName = "test"
    currentSchema = "public"
    user = "user"
    password = "user123"
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

This is now loaded using:

```
val db = Database.forConfig("database")
```

I can catch the ConnectionException or ping the machine and identify the IP for current master.

But, how can i over-write the `serverName` variable in the config and reload at runtime.

Is it a good design?

Answer (score 1):

You should set a domain name instead of ip address to `serverName`. This domain record must point to the master.
Such approach leaves most of high-availability concerns on the network level and doesn't leak them to an application code.

Comment: Unfortunately network team has some rules that requires the application team do it. I proposed the same approach but got this as the answer. +1 as that is my preferred approach as well.

Comment: Then you could just create a new instance of `Database` each time. Of course the previous one should be closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, you can use the command `SELECT pg_reload_conf();` to reload the Postgresql configuration without using the command-line. I found this page has some more information: https://www.heatware.net/postgresql/postgresql-reload-config-without-restarting/